# I run the code in distributed mode and my code run good in asynchronous mode; but the code run unsuccessful in synchronous mode

Tags: tensorflow

I run the code in distributed mode and my code run good in asynchronous mode; but the code run unsuccessful in synchronous mode.

```
opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=lr_placeholder, momentum=0.9) opt=tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(opt,replicas_to_aggregate=len(worker_hosts),total_num_replicas=len(worker_hosts),use_locking=True)
train_op = opt.minimize(full_loss, global_step=global_step)
val_op = validation_op(validation_step, vali_top1_error, vali_loss)
sync_replicas_hook = opt.make_session_run_hook(True)
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with training.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target, is_chief=True,hooks=[sync_replicas_hook]) as sess:
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1
292, in _do_call return fn(*args)
File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1
277, in _run_fn options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1
367, in _call_tf_sessionrun run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef missing attr 'reduction_type'
from Op handle:Ref(string); attr=dtype:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_UINT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]; attr=shape:shape; attr=container:string,default=""; attr=shared_name:string,default=""; attr=reduction_type:string,default="MEAN",allowed=["MEAN", "SUM"]; is_stateful=true>; NodeDef: {{node sync_replicas/conditional_accumulator}} = ConditionalAccumulator_class=["loc:@sync_replicas/SetGlobalStep"], container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[3,3,3,16], shared_name="conv0/conv:0/grad_accum", _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef missing attr 'reduction_type'
from Op handle:Ref(string); attr=dtype:type,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, ..., DT_UINT16, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]; attr=shape:shape; attr=container:string,default=""; attr=shared_name:string,default=""; attr=reduction_type:string,default="MEAN",allowed=["MEAN", "SUM"]; is_stateful=true>; NodeDef: {{node sync_replicas/conditional_accumulator}} = ConditionalAccumulator_class=["loc:@sync_replicas/SetGlobalStep"], container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[3,3,3,16], shared_name="conv0/conv:0/grad_accum", _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"